# Using codeigniter routes to leave out a part of the uri

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this uri `http://localhost/ur/index.php/reports/annual/gm/8312/44724286729` but the `annual` part serves the purpose of showing the user what report he/she is viewing.

The function that is therefore being mapped is `gm` with the parameters

```
public function gm($id,$telephone_number{
/**
General Meeting
*/
}
```

in `http://localhost/ur/index.php/reports/annual/gm/8312/44724286729`

My controller file is called `reports`.How would i use routes to ignore `annual` and only use `gm` and as my function and other sections of the uri as my parameters namely `8312/44724286729`?.

I have tried this in my `routes`

```
$route['annual/(:any)'] = "gm";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the dollar-sign syntax as such

```
$route['reports/annual/(:any)/(:any)'] = "reports/gm/$1/$2";
```

And in your `reports` controller the `gm` function will use `$1 and $2` as arguments.

P.S.: see the [URI Routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) section in CI manual.